# Facebook Messenger with Flask

Tags: python, facebook, heroku, flask, facebook-messenger

I'm trying to get the FB messenger API working using Python's Flask, adapting the following instructions: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/quickstart

So far, things have been going pretty well. I have verified my callback and am able to receive the messages I send using Messenger on my page, as in the logs in my heroku server indicate the appropriate packets of data are being received by my server. Right now I'm struggling a bit to send responses to the client messenging my app. In particular, I am not sure how to perform the following segment from the tutorial in Flask:

```
var token = "<page_access_token>";

function sendTextMessage(sender, text) {
  messageData = {
  text:text
}
request({
  url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
  qs: {access_token:token},
  method: 'POST',
  json: {
    recipient: {id:sender},
    message: messageData,
  }
}, function(error, response, body) {
  if (error) {
    console.log('Error sending message: ', error);
  } else if (response.body.error) {
    console.log('Error: ', response.body.error);
  }
});
}
```

So far, I have this bit in my server-side Flask module:

```
@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def chatbot_response():
    data = json.loads(req_data)
    sender_id  = data["entry"][0]["messaging"][0]["sender"]["id"]
    url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages"
    qs_value = {"access_token": TOKEN_OMITTED}
    json_response = {"recipient": {"id": sender_id}, "message": "this is a test response message"}
    response = ("my response text", 200, {"url": url, "qs": qs_value, "method": "POST", "json": json_response})
    return response
```

However, running this, I find that while I can process what someone send my Page, it does not send a response back (i.e. nothing shows up in the messenger chat box). I'm new to Flask so any help would be greatly appreciated in doing the equivalent of the Javascript bit above in Flask.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that works for me:

```
data = json.loads(request.data)['entry'][0]['messaging']
for m in data:
  resp_id = m['sender']['id']
  resp_mess = {
    'recipient': {
      'id': resp_id,
    },
    'message': {
      'text': m['message']['text'],
    }
  }
  fb_response = requests.post(FB_MESSAGES_ENDPOINT,
                              params={"access_token": FB_TOKEN},
                              data=json.dumps(resp_mess), 
                              headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'})
```

key differences:

`message` needs a `text` key for the actual response message, and you need to add the `application/json` `content-type` header.

Without the `content-type` header you get the `The parameter recipient is required` error response, and without the `text` key under `message` you get the `param message must be non-empty` error response.

Answer (score 1):

This is the Flask example using [fbmq library](https://github.com/conbus/fbmq) that works for me:

echo example :

```
from flask import Flask, request
from fbmq import Page

page = fbmq.Page(PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN)

@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
  page.handle_webhook(request.get_data(as_text=True))
  return "ok"

@page.handle_message
def message_handler(event):
  page.send(event.sender_id, event.message_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

In that scenario in your tutorial, the node.js application is sending an HTTP POST request back to Facebook's servers, which then forwards the content on to the client.

So far, sounds like your Flask app is only *receiving* (AKA *serving*) HTTP requests. The reason is that that's what the Flask library is all about, and it's the only thing that Flask does.

To *send* an HTTP request back to Facebook, you can use any Python HTTP client library you like. There is one called `urllib` in the standard library, but it's a bit clunky to use... try the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library.

Since your request handler is delegating to an outgoing HTTP call, you need to look at the response to this sub-request also, to make sure everything went as planned.

Your handler may end up looking something like

```
import json
import os
from flask import app, request
# confusingly similar name, keep these straight in your head
import requests

FB_MESSAGES_ENDPOINT = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages"

# good practice: don't keep secrets in files, one day you'll accidentally
# commit it and push it to github and then you'll be sad. in bash:
# $ export FB_ACCESS_TOKEN=my-secret-fb-token
FB_TOKEN = os.environ['FB_ACCESS_TOKEN']


@app.route('/', method="POST")
def chatbot_response():
    data = request.json()  # flasks's request object
    sender_id = data["entry"][0]["messaging"][0]["sender"]["id"]
    send_back_to_fb = {
        "recipient": {
            "id": sender_id,
        },
        "message": "this is a test response message"
    }

    # the big change: use another library to send an HTTP request back to FB
    fb_response = requests.post(FB_MESSAGES_ENDPOINT,
                                params={"access_token": FB_TOKEN},
                                data=json.dumps(send_back_to_fb))

    # handle the response to the subrequest you made
    if not fb_response.ok:
        # log some useful info for yourself, for debugging
        print 'jeepers. %s: %s' % (fb_response.status_code, fb_response.text)

    # always return 200 to Facebook's original POST request so they know you
    # handled their request
    return "OK", 200
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried running your example and got the following response from FB: "jeepers. 400: {"error":{"message":"(#100) param recipient must be non-empty.","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id": ""}". I also tried modifying params argument of the post request above with the ("recipient": sender_id) key/value pair, but I'm still getting the same error. Bizarre since the sender_id is definitely an actual numerical value. Any thoughts?

Comment: two avenues to pursue: first, debug with `print sender_id`  or `print send_back_to_fb` during the call to double check you're actually sending a value that makes sense -- always a good idea to do the real dumb sanity check. second, perhaps FB needs the correct "application/json" header in your request to understand the content you're sending, try passing the data (unserialized) in the `json` kwarg instead: `requests.post(FB_MESSAGES_ENDPOINT, params={"access_token": FB_TOKEN}, json=send_back_to_fb)`

Comment: One other handy debug tool for Facebook specifically, nice because sometimes their docs are confusing or out of date: try the graph explorer tool at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ ... you can easily reconstruct and play with the POST request you're attempting while removing some of the complexity of your larger two-way interaction.

Answer (score -1):

When doing responses in Flask, you have to be careful.  Simply doing a `return` statement won't return anything to the requester.

In your case, you might want to look at [`jsonify()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.json.jsonify).  It will take a Python dictionary and return it to your browser as a JSON object.

```
from flask import jsonify
return jsonify({"url": url, "qs": qs_value, "method": "POST", "json": json_response})
```

If you want more control over the responses, like setting codes, take a look at [`make_response()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.make_response)

Comment: "Simply doing a return statement won't return anything to the requester." This is not correct. Flask turns the return value from the function into a Response object automagically. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#about-responses